# Run Tomcat in debugging mode with system properties

Tags: tomcat, remote-debugging, system-properties

I am trying to run tomcat in debuging mode. In the startup I want to add also some system properties, but I could not achieve this. I am running :

```
    ./catalina.sh jpda run -Dtest.variable="value"
```

and when I try to access the value of the variable, I get always null:

```
    System.out.println(null == System.getProperty(test.variable)); //prints always true
```

Does somebody know any solution for this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried passing system variables to catalina.sh and I don't know if it works. You want to try setting the JAVA_OPTS environment variable in $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dtest.variable="value""
```